# iOS local notification was fired on wrong date time

Tags: ios, localnotification

I've created a old uilocalnotification, now, I want to update it, I searched on Google but there are no way to update the local notification. So, I decided to cancel it and create a new local notication:

```
- (void) cancelLocalNotificationByUserInfo: (NSDictionary *)dictInfo
{
    UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    NSArray *notifArr = [application scheduledLocalNotifications];

    for (int i=0; i<notifArr.count; i++) 
    {
        UILocalNotification* theNotif = (UILocalNotification *)[notifArr objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([theNotif.userInfo isEqual:dictInfo])
        {
            [application cancelLocalNotification:theNotif];
        }
    }
}

- (void) addLocalNotification: (NSDate *) fireDate soundName: (NSString *) soundName 
                    alertBody:  (NSString *) alertBody infoDict: (NSDictionary *)infoDict
{
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;

    localNotif.fireDate = fireDate;

    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    // Notification details
    localNotif.alertBody = alertBody;

    // Set the action button
    localNotif.alertAction = @"Show me";
    localNotif.hasAction = YES;

    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    localNotif.soundName = soundName;

    localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

    // Schedule the notification
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    [localNotif release];

}
```

But, everytime, I execute the addLocalNotification method, the old local notification is fired immediately. Please help me!

Comment: from where you call method addLocalNotification?

Comment: On another class, first, I call method cancelLocalNotificationByUserInfo, then, I call method addLocalNotification.